# Angular Library Project: how to import the files from the one secondry input point to another secondry entry point

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I am creating library project name ng-core which contain two secondry entry points following is the structure of my library projects

```
ng-core   // main entry point
     ng-core/services  // first secondry entry point
     ng-core/models    // second secondry entry point
```

now in ng-core/services entry point i wanted to access the file from the ng-core/models but when i access the file it is giving the the following error

```
error TS6059: File 'C:/Users/Fahad/Documents/Angular/libraries-workspace/projects/ng-core/src/models/Mashup.ngtypecheck.ts'

is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Users\Fahad\Documents\Angular\libraries-workspace\projects\ng-core\src\services'.
'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files
```

now my question is, is it possible to access the files of ng-core/models in the ng-core/services. i have seen same pattern in some of the projects on the github like this one https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/accordion/accordion.module.ts but not able to understand how they are achieving it

Here is the sample repository which i have created
https://github.com/FahadRS/libraries-workspace